# Github не загружает сайт на GitHub Pages

Tags: javascript, css, git, github, frontend

https://github.com/HardlyDaniel/firstcomplete.github.io
подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы отображался сайт?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74776/discussion-on-question-by-daniel-sadovskiy-github-----github-pa).

Answer (score 3):

Репозиторий с сайтом пользователя `username` должен называться `username.github.io`. Вот так:

https://github.com/HardlyDaniel/hardlydaniel.github.io

Переименуйте его из `hardlydaniel` в `hardlydaniel.github.io`.

---

Кстати, **проблема не в верхнем регистре**. Не нужно удалять или переименовывать учетку.

Comment: Серьёзно?  
Что-то я не наблюдаю разницы в регистре http://projectsoft-studionions.github.io/  
Есть документация и нужно следовать именно ей https://pages.github.com/

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft не понял, с каким утверждением вы не соглашаетесь. :)

Comment: Регистр абсолютно не причём. Не влияет он. Вы уже изменили свой комментарий в котором говорили о том, что должно быть в нижнем регистре.

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft я не говорил, что должно быть в нижнем. Наоборот, сказал что проблема не в регистре. :)

Comment: `Кстати, проблема не в верхнем регистре. Не нужно удалять или переименовывать учетку.` Было написано с точностью до наоборот. Закончим не нужную дискуссию, которая не несёт смысла)).

Comment: @АндрейProjectSoft я имел в виду именно это. Видимо, я неоднозначно написал, поэтому вы поняли с точностью до наоборот. Спасибо за замечание, переформулировал.

Answer (score 1):

Вот есть руководство от [htmlacademy](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/99-github-as-hosting).
У вас в название репозитория после **hardlydaniel** нету  **github.io**.

[image: скрин]

Answer (score 1):

Ссылку на сайт можно увидеть в настройках проекта на github.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]